# Strange issue with NSAutoreleasepool and NSLog

Tags: iphone, multithreading, uitableview, nslog, nsautoreleasepool

I have a strange issue which gets resolved if I put an NSLog statement in the code.
I have an UITableviewController with search bar. I am doing the initial fetch to populate the table in the following way:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool2 = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
  self.listContent = [MainFunctions populateArrayFromModel]; //Get the array populated here from the model data

  [pool2 release];
```

Inside the static method of MainFunctions, the array is populated like this:

```
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
MModel *mainModel = [[MModel alloc] init];
//get all results from FetchedResultsController
[mainModel release];
return resultsArray;
```

The above code works only if I follow a particular pattern, i.e I need to press the related tab first. If I go to another tab before I come here, this code hangs for some reason.

However, if I put some NSLog statements in the code, it consistently works. like below;

```
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
           NSLog(@"1");

MModel *mainModel = [[MModel alloc] init];
//get all results from FetchedResultsController
           NSLog(@"2");
//....code here
           NSLog(@"3");
//....code here
           NSLog(@"4");


[mainModel release];
return resultsArray;
```

I have tried taking it off and putting it back on multiple times and it consistently shows the same behaviour. What has NSLog got to do with this, I am baffled.

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: NSLog creates autoreleased strings? What happens if you use NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray array];

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have a hang/deadlock, you should dump the call stacks of each thread to figure out what's blocking.

To do this, put your app into the hung state and then press the Pause button (or from the menus, Product > Debug > Pause). You will then see the list of threads and their call stacks on the left. Expand each thread to view its call stack. You can also a text representation of the call stacks using one of the following commands in the debug console (depending on whether you're debugging with gdb or lldb):

- t a a bt (for gdb)
- thread backtrace all (for lldb)

If you need more help diagnosing the problem, collect a text backtrace using one of those commands and paste it into a comment so we can take a look.